# how to manage the ajax response in Dojo

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

Ok, this may be a dumb question, but I can't find a way to solve my problem. I have this function:

```
function getActivityObj(sysId, date) {

    var activityObj = dojo.xhrGet({
         url: 'calendar/display-subactivities',
         content: {'sysId': sysId, 'date': date},
         handleAs: 'json',
         load: function(result) {
            console.log(result); 
         },
         error: function(){
             alert("error");
         }
    });

    var ajaxResponse = activityObj.ioArgs.xhr.response;
    return ajaxResponse;
 }
```

The problem is that my ajaxResponse variable is always empty, but if in firebug, the xhr object the response property is not empty.
I will use the ajax response in several places in my code so what am I doing wrong or what would be a better way to call the ajax response? Thank you. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Asynchronous code requires you to be a little more careful. You need to explicitly chain the callbacks (via load, addCallback or then) in order to sequence actions and you must *not* assume that an IO action is done after the corresponding function call is returns.

Comment: Well, xhrGet is asynchronous (since you did not explicitly set it to synchronous), so the Ajax call does not go out until AFTER the function `getActivityObj` completes -- since JavaScript is single-threaded.  `xhrGet` does not perform the Ajax call, it **SCHEDULES** the Ajax call right after your function returns.  Therefore, `ajaxResponse` is **ALWAYS** going to be empty before the end of this function block.

Comment: Yes, now (after reading the answer and comments) I finally understood what is all this asynchronous/synchronous thing about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the `ajaxResponse` variable is empty when you call it because the `xhrGet()` call is made asynchronously, and the result is not actually available yet when you set `ajaxResponse` and return it from your function.

By the time you view it in firebug, the XHR response has completed but it just isn't there when your code executes.

`xhrGet()` returns a `dojo.Deferred` object.  You can use that to add a callback function for when it actually completes:

```
function getActivityObj(sysId, date) {
    var activityObj = dojo.xhrGet({
         url: 'calendar/display-subactivities',
         content: {'sysId': sysId, 'date': date},
         handleAs: 'json',
         load: function(result) {
            console.log(result); 
         },
         error: function(){
             alert("error");
         }
    });

    var ajaxResponse;

    // activityObj is a Deferred
    activityObj.addCallback(function() {
      // Use your deferred response 
      ajaxResponse = activityObj.ioArgs.xrh.response;

      // Now inside this function, do whatever you were going to do
      // with the xhr return data that you intended to return from
      // the wrapping function.
    });
 }
```

I am not certain if there's a good way to wrap the `xhrGet()` call in a function and attempt to return the response though, since it will always be deferred if called asynchronously.

If it is safe to block further execution until the `xhrGet()` call has actually returned data, you can call it synchronously.  Then your code as you have it will work without a deferred callback.  Instead you would typically do whatever work the returned data was intended for in the `xhrGet()`'s `load()` function.

```
var activityObj = dojo.xhrGet({
     // Call synchronously
     sync: true,
     url: 'calendar/display- subactivities',
     content: {'sysId': sysId, 'date': date},
     // etc...
```

Comment: I prefer using the `.then` promise methods instead of the original `addCallback`, etc, from Deferred. `then` lets you compose stuff in lots of neat ways.

Comment: @missingno I started back with dojo 1.2 before `.then()` was available (1.4 maybe?). I just haven't gotten into the habit of using it since I've not done a large project purely in newer 1.5+ code.

Comment: Promise semantics (e.g. `.then`) were added in 1.5.  You can actually chain callbacks with `addCallback`, `addErrback`, etc. as well, though they behave somewhat differently and the distinction is important.  IMO, best to learn the "new" way with promises going forward.  See also: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/05/03/robust-promises-with-dojo-deferred-1-5/ and http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/promises/

Comment: Wow! Thank you guys for all your answers/comments. Now I realise that I know so little about this topic. Thank you again!